# Using SaxParser to get an ID

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I'm currently trying to make a java file that can do an export with xml. The only thing I need to actually retrieve is the staff id's and nothing else.If my xml file looks like this:

```
<? xml version= "1.0" ?>
< company>
    < staff id = "22" >
           < firstname> kate </firstname >
           < lastname> kim </lastname >
           < nickname> lolo </nickname >
           < salary> 10560</ salary >
    </ staff>
    < staff>
           < firstname> Chelsea </firstname >
           < lastname> young</ lastname >
           < nickname> cheloung </nickname >
           < salary> 200700</ salary >
    </ staff>
    < staff id = "23" >
    < firstname> Dani </firstname >
           < lastname> Heil </lastname >
           < nickname> Heily </nickname >
           < salary> 300000</ salary >
    </ staff>
 </ company>
```

and my java code looks like this:

```
package xmlfunctions;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class saxParser {

 public static void main(String argv[]) {

 try {

 SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
 SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

 DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

 boolean bfname = false;


 public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

      System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

      if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
           bfname = true;
      }



 }

 public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
      String qName) throws SAXException {

      System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

 }

 public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

      if (bfname) {
           System.out.println("First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
           bfname = false;
      }



 }

 };

   saxParser.parse("KatesFile.xml", handler);

 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }

  }

 }
```

How can I change it to get it to display the staff id only? That is all I really want not the other tags. Can anyone help please? I'm very unsure as to how to get the id's on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of `id` in `startElement()`, using the parameter `attributes`.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("staff")) {
        System.out.println(attributes.getValue("id"));
    }
}
```

If there is no `id` in `<staff>`, the value is null.

Comment: Thank you you absolute legend!Helper of the day!

Comment: If I want to get the id and its a name rather than a number will it work the same? Just it won't work now I've tried using it on id's that have a name instead of a number

Comment: Yes, it will work the same. getValue() returns a String (or null). When your id is a number, it's actually a String representing a number. If you want an integer instead of a String, you can use Integer.parseInt()

Comment: Hmm wonder why it doesn't work the same then. Just wanted to double check to make sure it would work. Thanks Junior!

Comment: The name of the tag had a capital letter! It was Environment not environment haha